# MVC4 Default Route to point to an area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have 2 areas in my project:

```
Areas | Admin
Areas | FrontEnd
```

What I would like is when I visit the site, the default route should load Controllers / Views / Models from the `FrontEnd` area. It's normal to have `Url/Admin` for an admin panel but I would rather not have to force `Url/FrontEnd` (or some other variation). Basically I don't want to use the Controller / Model / View folders on the root level.

I'm not sure how to change the code to allow this or even it's an advisable method. Could someone provide some guidance please?

What I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { 
                    area = "Admin",
                    controller = "Home", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                },
                namespaces: new[] { "WebsiteEngine.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { 
                    area = "FrontEnd", 
                    controller = "Home", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                },
                namespaces: new[] { "WebsiteEngine.Areas.FrontEnd.Controllers" }
            );
```

However this produces an error:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I do have views available in the areas and this doesn't look like it's looking there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can just do something like this:

```
// Areas/Admin/AdminAreaRegistration.cs
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Admin"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin_Default", 
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new 
            {
                area = "Admin",
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            });
    }
}


// Areas/Admin/FrontEndAreaRegistration.cs
public class FrontEndAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "FrontEnd"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "FrontEnd_Default", 
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new 
            {
                area = "FrontEnd",
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
           });
    }
}

// Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ...
}
```

Now, in your `RouteConfig` class, you probably have a `Default` route set up. Bear in mind that as long as you call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas` *before* you call `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`, the routes that you set up in the areas may override the routes you set up in `RouteConfig`. (Routes are evaluated in the order they appear in the `Routes` collection, and `.MapRoute` pushes new routes to the end)

Comment: I did try something similar but I might of got it wrong. Thanks, I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Could you please see my edit. Note: I had to add Namespaces as it was complaining about Home being defined twice.

Comment: @webnoob Looks like it works if you define these routes in the respective `AreaRegistration` classes. I've tested this and it seems to work (for me at least). See my updated answer.

Comment: Did you remove the default route mapping in `RouteConfig.cs` as well?

Comment: @webnoob Yes, that's what I meant, but it may not be necessary. I thought that the default route will override any area routes, but it turns out that if you call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas` first, the area routes take priority.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What does `FrontEndConfig` and `AdminConfig` refer to as those references aren't there when I create a new area and they don't resolve to anything?

Comment: @webnoob Occasionally you'll want to have additional configuration packaged with your areas. This is usually done through a static class named `{Area}Config`. But that's not really relevant to the question, so I'll remove them.

Comment: Ok, sorted. Thanks, really appreciate your time and help :) One final question, is this a bad approach to dealing with a website with admin backend?

Comment: @webnoob Not at all. It seems like a fairly reasonable approach. I would only caution you that areas should be funtionally and logically distinct from one another as much as possible. If your `Admin` and `FrontEnd` components (models / views / controllers) are very tightly coupled, then you may need to refactor it a bit to pull common things into the main part of your site (outside of an area).

Comment: Ok, excellent advice (something I am just drawing up on paper now). Many thanks once again.